# Colors are inverted on JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to draw a grid of lines on a `JPanel` placed insided `JFrame` using a `BufferedImage`.

So far I have got the vertical lines working (sort of) but my query is in relation to the `Color` of the lines and background.

When I run the application the `JFrame` and `JPanel` appears but the `Color` of the background is black and the lines are `White`.  It's as though the Colors are inverted. (see image below)

[image: JPanel view]

I haven't set any `Color` in my Main class and my source code for the `JPanel` is as follows-

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    boolean[][] grid;
    BufferedImage image;
    Graphics2D imageG;

    public MyPanel(boolean[][] newGrid) {
        grid = newGrid;
        image = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        imageG = image.createGraphics();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Integer cellWidth = this.getWidth() / grid.length;

        for (Integer i = 0; i < grid.length + 1; i++) {
            imageG.drawLine(i * cellWidth, 0, i * cellWidth, this.getHeight());
        }

        Graphics2D tempg = (Graphics2D) g;
        tempg.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        //Draw BufferedImage
        tempg.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        //this.getGraphics().drawImage(lineImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: “I haven't set any colors in my main class.’ Then why are you expecting specific colors to be used when you paint?  Why not use [setColor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor-java.awt.Color-)?

Comment: You have to set your color using `imageG.setColor` and `tempg.setColor`. The default color is black, that's why you're getting a black background. I guess you setted the `imageG` color to white?

Comment: imageG.setColor(Color.red) does change the lines to red but the black background doesn't change even if I set the color of tempg.  I also tried it on g but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`** which **Represents an image with 8-bit RGBA color components packed into integer pixels.**

and earlier using **`BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`** which **Represents an image with 8-bit RGB color components packed into integer pixels.** also it lacks with **`transparent`** `Colors` as well as **`undefined`** `Colors` and thus it illustrates those with **`Color.BLACK`**.

rectified source code from above -

```
    public MyPanel(boolean[][] newGrid) {
        grid = newGrid;
        //Represents an image with 8-bit RGBA color components packed into integer pixels.
        image = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        imageG = image.createGraphics();
        //Set the single pixel line color to YELLOW using BufferedImage instance
        imageG.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Integer cellWidth = this.getWidth() / grid.length;

        Graphics2D tempg = (Graphics2D) g;
        //Set the blocks and rest of it part to color RED
        tempg.setColor(Color.RED);

        for (Integer i = 0; i < grid.length + 1; i++) {
            imageG.drawLine(i * cellWidth, 0, i * cellWidth, this.getHeight());
        }

        tempg.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        //Draw BufferedImage
        tempg.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        //this.getGraphics().drawImage(lineImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
```

hope this will help you, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that earlier but didnt seem to help.  But it works now.  Oh well.  Also imageG.Color(setColor.YELLOW) doesnt do anything.